# aws elastic beanstalk tomcat session management

Tags: amazon-web-services

Are there any other ways to implement session sharing on aws elastic bean tomcat other than using the AmazonDynamoDBSessionManagerForTomcat with dynamo db.

Also, has anyone run into problems after implementing AmazonDynamoDBSessionManagerForTomcat.

Thanks,
Sanket

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used DynamoDB for session management, but has been using Elasticache. In my case, I was ok for the session not to be persisted. Elasticache is in memory and generally reliable and doesn't go down. Depending on what your business is, it might be acceptable to ask user to login in any case of the very-unusual case of cache going down.

This https://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/ helps to achieve this in code.